# Model First database generator freezes my Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I'm new to the Entity Framework, and I know this is not suppose to happen, but maybe it is a known issue in the community so I thought I'd ask.

I created my model with 2 entities. When I wanted to create the database tables Visual Studio froze on me. I ran the script myself but then I needed to modify an attribute so it'd take null values, and againg I can't impact my new model to the database.

I looked for upgrades or anything with no luck. Is anybody experiencing anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told Joel I unisntalled my Visual Studio Premium and installed Ultimate, and guess what?! the problem is now fixed... the wizard finishes and I can see .sql file...

So, I don't know if it is one of those uninstall and install again issues or is it a bug with the Premium flavour, (very unlikely) but for me it solved after installed the Ultimate version

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this as well, even with a model with a single entity.  I installed the Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack and tried various generation strategies, but with no luck.

The Generate Database Wizard gets as far as to display the DDL, but when Finish is clicked VS freezes with CPU activity at 100%... for hours.  Upon killing the process and opening the solution, the model.edmx.sql is present, but opening it begins the 100% CPU activity and freeze again.

Comment: same thing here... what flavour of Visual Studio are you working with? I was using Premium and as I write these lines I'm installing Ultimate... I'll let you know how that works