# Visual Studio Freezes when Creating Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I installed MySql Windows Installer (that includes MySql connector for C# and MySql Visual Studio tools). When I create a new edmx model using the designer tool, I am able to connect to the MySql server and select my tables. When I click finish, though, Visual Studio freezes. It also freezes when I try and update the object from the database.

Here is the output information also:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'An
>   error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>
> Fatal error encountered during command
>   execution.        Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
>             Reading from the stream has failed.
>                 Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
>                     An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3983438/808532 which was resolved by installing Visual Studio Ultimate Edition. If that's not the version you have, try borrowing a dev machine with Ultimate to see if it has the same problem.

Comment: What version of MySQL, version of EF and have you applied services packs to VS?

Comment: Hello,
I am using Visual Studio Ultimate SP1, MySql 14.12, and it looks like I have EF v 3.5 (C:/Program Files/Reference Assemblies/framework/v3.5